# Criando e instalando meus prórpios pacotes

Tags: python

Olá.
Estou aprendendo Python há pouco tempo. Agora estou tentando criar meus próprios pacotes. Isso ajuda a organizar o código.

Mas me surgiu uma dúvida: alguém saberia dizer como posso instalar meus pacotes de modo que fiquem disponíveis para todos os meus projetos?

Uma ideia seria copiá-los manualmente para o diretório de cada projeto, mas além disso não ser nada elegante, vou ter que copiar novamente quando houver alterações nos pacotes. Certamente não é uma boa solução.

Então, será que é possível usar o ***pip*** para instalar meus pacotes em meus projetos e atualizá-los quando necessário?

Alguém poderia esclarecer sobre esse assunto? Existe algum outro procedimento mais indicado para se fazer esse gerenciamento de meus próprios pacotes?

Obrigado pela ajuda.

PS.: usando Python 3.9.1, PyCharm e Win10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se você escrever um setup.py  para seus projetos, mesmo sem colocar os pacotes no Pypi público, ou em um repositório privado, pode simplesmente ativar o virtualenv de outro projeto, e digitar `pip install  <caminho_do_setup_py_do_subprojeto>` . Se tem planos de evoluir os subprojetos com o tempo e quer que os projetos maiores sempre vejam o código mais recente, ponha a opção "-e" no "pip": `pip install  -e <caminho_do_setup_py_do_subprojeto>`

Então  o segredo é só: sempre usar virtualenvs para seus projetos (ou equivalente como pyenv, ou os similares que são mantidos pelas próprias IDEs) - e criar um setup.py mínimo para seus projetos. Com  tempo você evolui esses `setup.py`  para terem os meta-dados necessários para publicar seus pacotes no repositório público se quiser.

Aqui tem alguns exemplos da estrutura de pacotes e o que tem que ter no arquivo `setup.py`: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

Comment: Ótima explicação. Tenho uma dúvida quanto ao "pip install -e": com essa opção torna-se desnecessário usar "pip install -U" para atualizar a instalação de um pacote?

Comment: O `pip install -e` faz com que o Python use o projeto da pasta em que ele está no momento. Sem o `-e` ele  copia os arquivos par a pasta `lib/site-packages` do virtual-env, e passa a usar a cópia feita naquele instante. COmo com -e ele usa os arquivos que você está editando, não precisa ficar usando o "-U" toda hora, mas quando você subir a versão, mudar versão de pré-requisitos, ou mudar o setup.py, ai precisa do  `-U` sim, que pode ser junto com o `-e`: `pip install -U -e . `